# Android firebase error when using nested addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Android application using the FireBase. In the databas I added, I added two tables to one of the user publications. I put the publication information and the number of the URIs in order to retrieve the information through another table for each user's information. When I do this, I need to use the database event

```
(.addValueEventListener).
```

Is nested but I get an error which is

> (Error: (157, 33) error: local variable UserName is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final)

**This is the code used**

```
  private void UserPostInformation(final String key) {
    DatabaseReference historyDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ThePostting").child(key);
    historyDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                String IdHistory = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Long time = 0L;
                String foodname11 = "";
                String imagefood1 = "";
                String s = null;
                String name = "name";
                String UserName = "";
                for (DataSnapshot  child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    if (child.getKey().equals("time")) {
                        time = Long.valueOf(child.getValue().toString());

                    }
                    if (child.getKey().equals("FoodName")) {
                        foodname11 = child.getValue().toString();

                    }

                    if (child.getKey().equals("profileImageUrl")) {
                        imagefood1 = child.getValue().toString();
                    }
                    if (child.getKey().equals("UserID")) {


                        s = child.getValue().toString();

                    }
                }

                UserIDGetInfo =  s;


                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(UserIDGetInfo);
                databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {

                            Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                            if (map.get("name")!=null)
                            {

      //error is her where using the String UserName get the error  local variable UserName is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final)
                            UserName= map.get("name").toString();
                        }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                HistoryObject obj =new HistoryObject(IdHistory , getDate(time),foodname11 , imagefood1 , UserName);
                resultHistory.add(obj);
                mhistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

**this part of database I Using**
[image]

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how multithreading works.  You are very likely creating HistoryObject with  userName = null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `UserName` as property of the class , also you properly will get null value for `UserName` because you setting the instance of `HistoryObject` before the loading of User is done

checkout my fix

```
private String UserName = "";
private void UserPostInformation(final String key) 
{
    DatabaseReference historyDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ThePostting").child(key);
    historyDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                String IdHistory = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Long time = 0L;
                String foodname11 = "";
                String imagefood1 = "";
                String s = null;
                String name = "name";
                UserName = "";
                for (DataSnapshot  child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    if (child.getKey().equals("time")) {
                        time = Long.valueOf(child.getValue().toString());

                    }
                    if (child.getKey().equals("FoodName")) {
                        foodname11 = child.getValue().toString();

                    }

                    if (child.getKey().equals("profileImageUrl")) {
                        imagefood1 = child.getValue().toString();
                    }
                    if (child.getKey().equals("UserID")) {


                        s = child.getValue().toString();

                    }
                }

                UserIDGetInfo =  s;


                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(UserIDGetInfo);
                databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {
                            Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            if (map.get("name")!=null)
                            {
                                UserName= map.get("name").toString();
                            }


                            HistoryObject obj = new HistoryObject(IdHistory , getDate(time),foodname11 , imagefood1 , UserName);
                            resultHistory.add(obj);
                            mhistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I do this But not get the Information I need ( not get the UserName )

Answer (score 0):

either declare username as class variable or change the modifier to final, error is cleary saying `local variable UserName is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`
So declare it as `final Stirng userName`